# GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_debug_log_valist: assertion `category != NULL' failed?

Tags: gstreamer, vala

How might I chase down the root cause of this error message?

> (test:1090): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_debug_log_valist: assertion
>   `category != NULL' failed

I am using `--gst-debug=GST_REFCOUNTING:5` to debug intermittent issues in the code that can take more than 10 hours to reproduce. The pipeline seems to work fine even with the gst-debug error message. Should I be concerned about the GStreamer-CRITICAL error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I usually do is run the program in gdb with a G_DEBUG=fatal-criticals environment variable (see the [Running GLib Applications](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-running.html) section of the GLib manual) in gdb and [use gdb to get a backtrace](https://wiki.gnome.org/Community/GettingInTouch/Bugzilla/GettingTraces/Details#Obtaining_a_stack_trace_using_GDB)... something like

```
G_DEBUG=fatal-criticals gdb -ex run --args ./test arg1 arg2 ...
```

If you don't want to actually run the program in gdb you can [use a core dump instead](https://wiki.gnome.org/Community/GettingInTouch/Bugzilla/GettingTraces/Details#Obtaining_a_stack_trace_from_a_core_dump).

Once you get a trace you should be able to find the offending code fairly easily.  The message might be harmless and/or an issue internal to GStreamer, but I would at least check it out if I were you...  criticals like that are often an indicator of a serious issue, like a segfault waiting to happen.

Note that the 1090 in that message likely refers to the [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier), not a line number in the generated C.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this message is trying to tell you that there's a gstreamer log message somewhere in the code that simply lacks a category (one like GST_REFCOUNTING or ). As you only want to see log messages concerning GST_REFCOUNTING messages gstreamer can't be sure whether or not this specific message is important or not. Unless you've written your own plugin or called some of the [Logging functions](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/pwg/html/section-checklist-debug.html) yourself, I'd guess this is most likely an issue of gstreamer itself or one of its plugins.

But it's not one that should cause any trouble other than ill-categorized log messages